# How do I write a string to a .csv file?

Tags: c++, csv

I currently have this code, but I would like to be able to output to a .csv file, rather than just print to screen. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string Weather_test;

int main()
{
    ifstream Weather_test_input;
    Weather_test_input.open("/Users/MyName/Desktop/Weather_test.csv");

    getline(Weather_test_input, Weather_test, '?');

    Weather_test.erase(remove_if(Weather_test.begin(), Weather_test.end(), ::isalpha), Weather_test.end());

    cout << Weather_test;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to make a file handler - also try searching i'm sure you can find an answer here

Comment: Just google for C++ write to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks people you here are all truly amazing!

I managed to get my final piece of code which (removes all letters of the alphabet from my .csv file). Here it is for posterity

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string Weather_test;

int main()
{
    ifstream Weather_test_input;
    Weather_test_input.open("/Users/MyName/Desktop/Weather_test.csv");

    getline(Weather_test_input, Weather_test, '?');

    Weather_test.erase(remove_if(Weather_test.begin(), Weather_test.end(), ::isalpha), Weather_test.end());

    ofstream Weather_test_output("/Users/MyName/Desktop/Weather_test_output.csv", ios::app);
    Weather_test_output << Weather_test << std::endl;
    Weather_test_output.close();

    cout << Weather_test;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks again all!

Answer (score 2):

If the Weather_test string is formatted properly.

```
ofstream Weather_test_output("path_goes_here.csv", ios::app);  
      // this does the open for you, appending data to an existing file
Weather_test_output << Weather_test << std::endl;
Weather_test_output.close();
```

If it is not formatted properly then you need to separate it into "fields" and write them with commas between them.  That's a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a string to a CSV file is like writing a string to any file:

```
std::string text = "description"
output_file << description << ", " << 5 << "\n";
```

In your example, you can't write to an `ifstream`.  You can write to `ofstream` and `fstream` but not **`ifstream`**.

So either open the file for reading and writing or close after reading and open as writing.

Answer (score 0):

To write to `csv` is to create an `ostream` and open file named `"*.csv"`. You can use `operator<<` on this object in the same way as you have used it previously to write to the standard output, std::cout:

```
std::ofstream f;
f.open( "file.csv", std::ios::out);
if ( !f) return -1;
f << Weather_test;
f.close();
```